# Template Proposals in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, hotkeys, code-editor

In Eclipse, I can put my cursor on a method name and hit ctrl-space and I get a list of available template proposals.

In Android Studio, when I'm typing a method name and open paren, I get a list of template proposals, but afterwards, how do I see the list again?  I've already got *show quick doc on mouse move*, but that only shows the method signature I selected at first.  I want to see alternatives to what I selected the first time through.

How do I show alternative method signatures, aka alternative *template proposals*?

EDIT:
Thanks to AndroidMechanic for answering *Ctrl-P*.
Here is what it looks like in Android Studio: [image: Android Studio Template Proposal Example]

Here is what it looks like in Eclipse: [image: Eclipse Template Proposal Example].  Notice that you're presented with the documentation in Eclipse, which I find helpful.  But *Ctrl-P* gets me most of the way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android studio to see all method overloads click inside the parenthesis and hit `Ctrl + P`. This will show you the different combinations you could pass as parameters to a method.